# I can't make sense out of this line from A CHRISTMAS CAROL

Tags: meaning

Man, if man you be in heart, not adamant, forbear that wicked cant until you have discovered what the surplus is, and where it is.

what is the meaning of 'man you be in heart'?

what is the meaning of 'forbear that wicked cant'?

Comment: It's ***cant*** (a noun), not ***can't***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "if" is important. It introduces a clause expressing a statement not known to be true. In older forms of English, such clauses used subjunctive forms of the word "be."

So the clause means "if you are a man (which is not necessarily true) rather than a stone."

Comment: can you answer second question?

Comment: "To forbear" is a word not much used today, but means "to refrain," "to not do." "Cant" means "sanctimonious speech." So the phrase means "stop that false moralizing."

Answer (score 0):

The ghost is warning Scrooge not to dismiss the “Surplus population” unless Scrooge is confident that he knows where the line for what is surplus will be drawn. That Scrooge considers himself better, is ridiculous to a god that cannot fathom the idea of social class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).